# asp.net core authentication with IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppRoleClaim, AppUserToken>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create database from Code first model. When I run `dotnet ef migrations add` or debug application I get error:

```
TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0], 'OpPISWeb.Models.AppUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TUser'.
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(RuntimeTypeHandle handle, IntPtr* pInst, int numGenericArgs, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
```

in code:

```
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppWebContext, int>()
```

My code in ConfigureServices is:

```
        var res = services
            .AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(config =>
            {
                config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;
            })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppWebContext, int>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

and my EF models are:

```
[Table("Roles")]
public partial class AppRole : IdentityRole<int, AppUserRole, AppRoleClaim>
{
}
[Table("RoleClaims")]
public partial class AppRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<int>
{
}
[Table("Users")]
public partial class AppUser : IdentityUser<int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin>
{
}

//same for UserClaim, UserLogin, UserRole, UserToken
```

and my DBContext:

```
public partial class AppWebContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppRoleClaim, AppUserToken>
{

    public AppWebContext() : base() {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=...");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity
            .HasKey(u => u.Id);
            entity.Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity
            .HasKey(u => u.Id);
            entity.Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserClaim>(entity =>
        {
            entity
            .HasKey(u => u.Id);
            entity.Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity
            .HasKey(u => new { u.RoleId, u.UserId });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppRoleClaim>(entity =>
        {
            entity
            .HasKey(u => u.Id);
            entity.Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        });
    }
}
```

What did I miss? I am new in ASP.net and ASP.NET Core.
I am using version 1.1.

Complete error:

```
An error occurred while starting the application.

TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0], 'OpPISWeb.Models.AppUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TUser'.
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(RuntimeTypeHandle handle, IntPtr* pInst, int numGenericArgs, ObjectHandleOnStack type)

ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 'OpPISWeb.Models.AppUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey]' violates the constraint of type 'TUser'.
System.RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo definition, RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e)

TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0], 'OpPISWeb.Models.AppUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TUser'.
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(RuntimeTypeHandle handle, IntPtr* pInst, int numGenericArgs, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(Type[] inst)
System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)

Show raw exception details
ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 'OpPISWeb.Models.AppUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey]' violates the constraint of type 'TUser'.
System.RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo definition, RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e)
System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.GetDefaultServices(Type userType, Type roleType, Type contextType, Type keyType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.AddEntityFrameworkStores<TContext, TKey>(IdentityBuilder builder)
OpPISWeb.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

Show raw exception details
.NET Core X64 v4.1.1.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 1.1.0-rtm-22752    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393    |   Need help? - Yes I do. Please.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> When you are customizing ASP.NET Core Identity, you should not use
>   AddEntityFrameworkStores anymore. Because it will override all of your
>   previous settings and customization to default Identity services.

Quote from Github answer [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1082).

Comment: This is funny. Haha! Someone puts an effort to answer your question, later you posted your answer and marked it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is caused by `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppWebContext, int>()`. Take a look at HaoK's responses toward the end of this post:
https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1001.

Specially these 2

> "AddEntityFrameworkStores can only be called with a user that derives from IdentityUser. If you are specifying more generic arguments, use IdentityBuilder.AddUserStore() instead."
>
> "AddEntityFrameworkStores can only be called with a role that derives from IdentityRole. If you are specifying more generic arguments, use IdentityBuilder.AddRoleStore() instead."

So if you want to override `UserClaim`, `UserLogin` and all others, you need to implement your own `UserStore` and `RoleStore`, and use `AddUserStore<T>()` and `AddRoleStore<T>()` instead of `AddEntityFrameworkStores`.

**AppUserStore**

```
public class AppUserStore : UserStore<AppUser, AppRole, AppDbContext, int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppUserToken, AppRoleClaim>
{
    public AppUserStore(AppDbContext dbContext)
        : base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    protected override AppUserToken CreateUserToken(AppUser user, string loginProvider, string name, string value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override AppUserLogin CreateUserLogin(AppUser user, UserLoginInfo login)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override AppUserRole CreateUserRole(AppUser user, AppRole role)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override AppUserClaim CreateUserClaim(AppUser user, Claim claim)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**AppRoleStore**

```
public class AppRoleStore : RoleStore<AppRole, AppDbContext, int, AppUserRole, AppRoleClaim>
{
    public AppRoleStore(AppDbContext dbContext)
        : base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    protected override AppRoleClaim CreateRoleClaim(AppRole role, Claim claim)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And in your `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>()
    .AddUserStore<AppUserStore>()
    .AddRoleStore<AppRoleStore>()
    // Components that generate the confirm email and reset password tokens
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Now I do think you need to create your own version of `UserManager`, `RoleManager` and `SignInManager` as well. I will update with more codes here later on after I figure everything out.

Answer (score -2):

This is how I did it on my project

[image]

Comment: Please review [answer] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1030169)